# How do I configure CNAME for S3 websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cname

I am trying to host my static website using S3. I have a domain that I bought outside of AWS. The URL for my bucker `http://my-website.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. My domain name is `my-website.com`. I have tried everything but I cannot wrap my head around how I should be configuring **CNAME** so that my URL does not look messed up. I tried forwarding but that does not work for obvious reasons.

Please suggest solutions.

Comment: Unless you're using Route53 to manage your domain, this question is not related to AWS, but to how to configure CNAME records with your domain registrar.

Comment: Your CNAME record (which should be a Route 53 A-Record Alias, not a CNAME) should not result in the URL looking "messed up."  Please explain what is messed up about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your DNS provider is

1. You're using [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) then you need to go to the Hosted Zone for `my-website.com` and add a **A** record for `my-website.com` that points to the bucket. You must set `Alias` to true for this to work.
2. If you're using a different DNS provider you can't route Apex domain (my-wesite.com, without www, or another subdomain in front). You'll be able to add a CNAME record for a subdomain that points to the S3 web endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I realized this after a lot of reading yesterday. Thank you.